# Python method defaults based off of class __init__ args

Tags: python

I want my methods defaults within a class to be set to what was passed in through the `__init__` method. Something like this:

```
class Foo(object):

    def __init__(self, loc=None):
        self.loc = loc

    def test(self, loc=self.loc):
        print loc


test = Foo()
test.test()
>>> None

test = Foo('foobar')
test.test()
>>> foobar
```

Is this possible or another way of achieving this?

EDIT: I know this current code is not possible but something that would function like this is what I'm looking for.

Thanks

Comment: having self.loc in the method call of test errors out when I run it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Default argument values are evaluated at the point of function definition in the *defining* scope, but `self` is an argument only available during function call.

See an example:

```
i = 5
def f(arg = i): print arg
i = 6
f()
```

will print 5. [Visualization](http://goo.gl/obHGV) on python-tutor.

It is a common pattern to default an argument to `None` and add a test for that in the code:

```
def test(self, loc = None):
    if loc is None:
       loc = self.loc
    print loc
```

Answer (score 2):

Do something like this:

```
def test(self, loc = None):
    if loc is None:
       loc = self.loc
```